# How to make a phone mask with Regexp

Tags: javascript, regex

how to make a phone number mask name regexp pattern

```
/(^8|7|\+7)((\d{10})|(\s\(\d{3}\)\s\d{3}\s\d{2}\s\d{2}))/
```

**UPD**

This code works for me, but I do not know how to do how to make +7 automatically become at the beginning

```
var x = value.replace(/\D/g, '').match(/(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})/);

var result = !x[2] ? x[1] : '(' + x[1] + ') ' + x[2] + (x[3] ? '-' + x[3] : '');

setPhone(result)
```

Comment: what sort of phone number? international? local? mobile? You should create a list of the numbers you consider valid phone numbers and invalid phone numbers first, and then try and defined a matching regexp yourself - there are many online tools to help you. Come back here if you cannot get it to work and provide all the information and test cases.

Comment: @JohnXF I want a person to be able to enter only a phone in the format +7 (000) 000-00-00
I can't find the information I need and I don't have enough experience to do it myself

Comment: rexep are not simple, and even experienced coders can struggle with them. However by just asking for an answer you will learn little and it is always worth at least trying to understand what you are doing. Above, you only gave one example number. Is the bit in parenthesis - (000) - optional? is the + mandatory? As I said above, you should define the valid and invalid numbers you want to match and then create at least an initial regex yourself. As I said, there are many online tools to help you do that and to explain the simple and complex parts of a regex.

Comment: What's wrong with the given regex?

Comment: The given regex is almost correct. You can use `^\+7\s\(\d{3}\)\s\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{2}`, see: https://regexr.com/6b46m

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
^\+7\s?\(?\d{3}\)?\s?\d{3}-?\d{2}-?\d{2}$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DNS9XS/1)

Answer (score -1):

```
^(\+\d{1,2}\s)?\(?\d{3}\)?[\s.-]\d{3}[\s.-]\d{4}$
```

This works for me but needs to define what kind of regex you want like what country and states phone number